# Comparing participants' answers to actual correct answers

Tags: chi-squared-test

I have a questionnaire with Google translations where some of these translations are correct and some are not. Students had to tick if they agree or disagree with these translations.
Now I don't know which method to use to analyse these results. I would like to group the correct translations and the incorrect ones and then analyse those groups based on students' gender, grade, etc. to see if there are any differences. Or if you have a better solution please let me know.
Thank you very much

Comment: Do you just want to show whether men are different from women overall or do you want to do it question by question? I suspect that the answer is logistic regression in either case.

Comment: I was thinking to group correct translations and incorrect ones because I think it would be easier and easier to look at. And yes, I want to show which gender is better at perceiving correct/incorrect translation.

Comment: But if I wanted to do question by question could I simply use Chi-square test?

Comment: That can be handled by logistic regression. If you are starting from scratch here perhaps the best thing is to use your favourite search engine to look  for "logistic regression ucla" as they have pages about most of the popular programs with worked examples.

Comment: Using $\chi^2$ would only help to look at one predictor at a time so you could not look at grade and sex simultaneously.

Comment: I didn't mean to look at gender and grade at the same time, I want to look at the group of correct translations according to gender.

Comment: And I already have all data inserted in SPSS.

Comment: I do not use SPSS so cannot help with specifics.